# What's the name of log error viewer from U.Budgie?

Tags: logs, tools

Recently have moved on Mate, and I would like to have that tool that informs me with various types of errors from log files with priority 3. On Budgie, I could launch it by typing "Logs" name in menu. In the left column there's a list of types, such as Application, System, Important etc. And the rest part of window shows the list of errors (in Important section), and when I click on each, it either looks through all similar errors to the one I clicked, or opens a new window with a little more detailed info, like application name ("sender" field), time of error and its description.

I liked it, since it helped me find the system problems within one click, instead of browsing tons of logs (that's what most of log viewer apps do). I would appreciate if somebody remembers the name of the tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, it is [gnome-logs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Logs). Too sad it's not build-in on most(-ish) distros, it's a very useful thing, imo